# Error when installing ROS Neotic on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

When I try following the ROS wiki guide to install the ROS Noetic on my Ubuntu 20.04 (It's WSL), I met with this error about the key setting
up.

`Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).`

`gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

The command I try executing is

`curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

It seems that the reason is because `apt-key` is not supported on Ubuntu 20.04. So, does anyone know how to change this command? Besides, I think that ROS wiki should update their document accordingly.

Comment: The command you used should still work. Please edit your post to show us the output of this command (as **text formatted as Code**, not as an image of the screen): `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc`

Comment: @Mike973 Thanks! I have modified the format. But the command truly doesn't work. And the warnings are shown in the post. Or do these warnings mean the command has run successfully?

Comment: I asked you to show us the output from a **different** command to confirm that `curl` is working. What I gave you is the entire command. Also please show us the output of `which curl`

Comment: Ohhh, sorry, I can make sure that the `curl` works.

Comment: If you solved this, please answer your own question and explain what the problem was, and what you did to fix it.